# How to Import a TrueType Font (or OpenType Font) into a custom ESRI Style without doing it one symbol at a time?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, style, font

Creating a personal TrueType or OpenType Font with font creation software is easy. Pulling that creation into a custom ESRI Style as (e.g.) Character Marker Symbols is a tedious affair. Is there a tool or scripting method of populating a custom style with my new TTF of approximately 140 characters?

Comment: use windows character map and copy and paste your text http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_Map - had to do this for Cyrillic fonts http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic#Cyrillic_alphabets

Comment: @Mapperz How is this method any different than using ArcMap's Style Manager and adding one Marker Symbol at a time, 10 or 12 clicks each? With 140 symbols that's 1680 clicks - a long and tedious process prone to human error.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this?

Comment: @BenedekSimo -- Alas no! Something like this, [Creating Your Own Symbol Style Sets](http://www.cfgis.org/getattachment/91d6ab88-f593-494a-af77-a6a754246ff4/Creating-Your-Own-Symbol-Style-Sets.aspx), is what Mapperz was getting at but I find it too tedious.

Comment: Oh boy, it does seems complicated! But thank you anyways!